# use jquery each to transfer link and assign it to new element

Tags: jquery

I'm kind confused on how to use jquery each store value from link then assign it new to link element.

Here's the markup.

```
<div class="box">
<a href="linkhere">Title</a>
<a href="transferhere" class="mybtn">New Link</a>
</div>

<div class="box">
<a href="linkhere">Title</a>
<a href="transferhere" class="mybtn">New Link</a>
</div>

<div class="box">
<a href="linkhere">Title</a>
<a href="transferhere" class="mybtn">New Link</a>
</div>
```

Here's what I did

```
$(".box").each(function(){
        var hyperLinkValue = $('.box > a').attr('href');
        $('a.mybtn').attr("href", hyperLinkValue);
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work?. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current logic is selecting *every* `a` and `.mybtn` element in the DOM within each iteration of the loop. To fix this you should use the `this` keyword to reference the element in the current iteration of the `each()` loop only:

```
$(".box").each(function() {
  var hyperLinkValue = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  $(this).find('a.mybtn').attr("href", hyperLinkValue);
});
```

That being said, you can simplify the logic providing a function to `attr()` which returns the value to set:

```js
$("a.mybtn").attr('href', function() {
  return $(this).prev('a').attr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <a href="linkhere">Title</a>
  <a href="transferhere" class="mybtn">New Link</a>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <a href="linkhere">Title</a>
  <a href="transferhere" class="mybtn">New Link</a>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <a href="linkhere">Title</a>
  <a href="transferhere" class="mybtn">New Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterating over the `.box`es, iterate over the *first child* of the `.box`es. Then, referencing `this` inside the handler will get you to the `linkhere`s, and calling `.next()` on it will get you to the `transferlinkhere`:

```js
$('.box > :first-child').each(function() {
  $(this).next().prop(
    'href',
    this.href
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <a href="linkhere">Title</a>
  <a href="transferhere" class="mybtn">New Link</a>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <a href="linkhere">Title</a>
  <a href="transferhere" class="mybtn">New Link</a>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <a href="linkhere">Title</a>
  <a href="transferhere" class="mybtn">New Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!